# explaining reactjs doc example on dynamic context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

under reactjs doc **Dynamic Context** [examples](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#examples) specifically on the second file  called **themed-button.js**

They used **button** element and I'm trying to understand this points:

- **first:** they closed it like a component `<button/>` I don't know why ?

  I think It will render empty button
- **second:** what this exprestion `{...props}` doing inside the button

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

They use self close tag for the components that deos not has a childern
take a look here [react docs - JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

and if you look down in the examples, you can see how they used `ThemedButton`

```
// An intermediate component that uses the ThemedButton
function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <ThemedButton onClick={props.changeTheme}>
      Change Theme
    </ThemedButton>
  );
}
```

and about this expression `{...props}`
you are using it in case you want to add more props but you don't know there name yet. May be you want to add more props to your button like `style`, `disabled`, ...

Comment: okay thanks, but as the link you referred *self-closing form of the tag if there are no children.* so it will render `empty button` still why ?. about `{...props}` I understand it copes the props obj but nothing passed to `ThemedButton ` as a props So I asked what it doing ?

Answer (score 0):

props will be passed to ThemedButton from its parent as mentioned in the code snippet above

```
// An intermediate component that uses the ThemedButton
function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <ThemedButton onClick={props.changeTheme} label="save" placeholder="click to save" className="info-btn">
      Change Theme
    </ThemedButton>
  );
}
```

the props object will contain all the passed properties when initiated from Toolbar component and they'll be passed from ThemedButton to its sub child button component as props as well.